# Puppeteer | Launching and running Chrome (not Chromium) on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, puppeteer

[image: It is browser choosing stage, i clicked Chrome and launch.json appears, i was clicking node.js before, and using Chromium]

I have tried my .js project with Chromium but it was very slow rather than Chrome's itself. So i decided running my program with Chrome on VS Code but this time VS Code created a file named launch.json and i couldn't achieve to bind index.js to launch.json.

Summary of my question, how can i run my script in Chrome on VS Code? What should i do to run launch.json and index.js together? I will leave my code blocks now.

launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "url",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }

        
    ]
}
```

index.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs/promises')

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.waitForSelector('selector')
    await browser.close()

}
start()
```

I didn't try anything essentially, because i don't know about solution. I researched on Google, Stackoverflow and Youtube too many times (2 days at least, maybe i can't find keyword because of my poor English) I described my problem as much as i can.

I must add, executablePath solution didn't work for me and

" crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. "
this error message appears on my debbugging console.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running program with Windows PowerShell is solution. The code that i execute:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs/promises')

async function start() {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: false,
       executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' })
   const page = await browser.newPage()
   await page.waitForSelector('selector')
   await browser.close()

}
start()
```

So yes, executablePath is a solution, if you don't try that on VS Code.